# show most views custom taxonomies from wordpress post loop and remove duplicated values

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy

I'm creating a loop where it shows the most visited taxonomies on the site. I know WordPress doesn't track taxonomies and categories views. So I inserted a tracker in the posts to create a loop with the most viewed posts and then show the taxonomies of that post on the homepage.

Code credit to [isitwp](https://www.isitwp.com/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/)

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
 
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

After inserting the tracker create a loop to show the most viewed posts

Here the code:

```
<?php
$popular = array(
    'post_type'         => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page'    => 8,
    'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count', // setPostViews($postID) function;
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'offset'            => 1,
);

$popular_loop = new WP_Query( $popular );

if( $popular_loop->have_posts() ){

    while( $popular_loop->have_posts() ) : $popular_loop->the_post();

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'seasons' ); 

        foreach($terms as $term) {

            $ids = $term->term_id;

            $arr = explode( ',', $ids );

            $arr_unique = array_unique( $arr );

            $str = implode( $arr_unique );

            if($term->parent != 0){
                /**
                 * Taxonomie has children get the parent ID
                */
                echo '<p>Return parent unique:' . $str . '</p>';
            
            } else {
                /**
                 * Taxonomie has NO children get the current taxonomy ID 
                */
                echo '<p>Return unique:' . $str . '</p>';
            }

        }

    endwhile;

} else {
    return false;
} wp_reset_postdata();
```

The problem is that as I want it to show the `name, id, link, image, etc`. of the parent taxonomy of the most viewed posts, they start to repeat themselves and I would like to exclude the duplicates so it doesn't get repeated every time someone accesses a post different from same taxonomy i tried `array_unique()` but it keeps returning me duplicate values.

Is there any way to delete this duplicate values inside the loop?

Comment: _"i tried array_unique()"_ - makes little sense at this point, because you are looking at the terms of _one_ single post there. Of course those _are_ already unique. You can not handle "making" the data unique, and outputting it, in one and the same loop. You need to gather all the terms across _all_ posts first, then make them unique, and then loop over the result to output the unique terms.

Comment: `$ids = $term->term_id; $arr = explode( ',', $ids );` does not make much sense to begin with - you got a _single_ ID at this point, there are no commas in there to explode that value by.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, I apologize if my question was confusing or didn't please some users

Here the code:

```
<?php 
$popular = array(
    'post_type'         => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page'    => 8,
    'order'             => 'ASC',
);

$popular_loop = new WP_Query( $popular );

if( $popular_loop->have_posts() ){

    // Get the terms array
    $unique = [];

    while( $popular_loop->have_posts() ) : $popular_loop->the_post();

        // Taxonomy loop post
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'seasons' ); 

        foreach($terms as $term) {

            // Get the unique array from loop
            if( !in_array( $term->term_id, $unique ) ){
                $unique[] = $term->term_id;

                // Get unique ID from Taxonomy
                echo $term->term_id;

                // Get Unique name fromt Taxonomy
                echo $term->name;
                
            }

        }

    endwhile;

} else {

    echo 'Nothing';

} wp_reset_postdata();
```